# On form load hide the form if a text file doesn't exist and show another form

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to check if a file exists on load of one form, if it doesn't I want to hide the form and call a second form, unfortunately I don't seem able to hide the first form. Hope this makes some sort of sense

```
    private void frmTick_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sPath = @"C:\develop\operate.xml";

        if (!File.Exists(sPath))
        {
            this.Visible=false;
            var frmCheckTick = new frmCheckTick();
            frmCheckTick.Show();

        }
    }
```

So I want to show frmCheckTick, which works, but hide frmTick which isn't happening, and yes have tried .Hide().

Comment: Do you want to show only the first or second form exclusively when the application opens? Or after something happens? Or repeatedly opening and closing forms?

Comment: It's -kinda- still loading.. that's why you can't hide it. The best approach should be, set visible false of frmTick (via form properties), and if file exists set visible true on load. Also, beginInvoke - hide(); function will solve the problem but using this; your form will be shown in 1 sec and disappear. So just change the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to hide the form on load

```
private void frmTick_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sPath = @"C:\develop\operate.xml";

    if (!File.Exists(sPath))
    {
        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
           Hide();
        }));
        var frmCheckTick = new frmCheckTick();
        frmCheckTick.Show();

    }
}
```

Hope it helps.